# How to use a list in a list in report builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting, report-builder

I'm currently using Microsoft SQL Report Builder to create a custom report for my data. I have a table of customers, a table of devices and a table of jobs (each customer has a couple of devices, each device has a couple of jobs).

What I want is a list of customers, and when I click on a customer it should expand and show all associated devices, and when I click on the device it should expand and show all jobs.

Should I just use a list in a list in a list? Or should I embed a subreport inside my list? Should I split all 3 tables in different datasets? Or just use 1 dataset?

I imagine there are a lot of different options (I did my research online) but there seems to be little consensus about whether it's a good idea to use subreports or not for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion, it depends on the complexity of the details view.

If I'm showing a sample list of values in each view then I'd rather use a List inside a List, inside a List.

For example:

```
[+] Customer Id + Customer Name
    [+] DeviCe Id + Device Name
        |------------|-----------------|
        | Job Id Job | Job Description |
        |------------|-----------------|
        |------------|-----------------|
        |------------|-----------------|
```

But, if the details view have a more complex structure, like graphics + tables or matrix, then I use a subreport.

Comment: Thanks for you opinion on this matter. It makes sense to me. I am going to use a list in a list for now. Is it a good idea to have all tables (with their columns) in 1 dataset or should I have different datasets for each list?

Comment: You can use a single select if you're using a fully related tables. Let me point you this article of Patrick LeBlanc with a full example in this question. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/microsoft_in_education/2013/03/09/ssrs-using-a-list-item-to-display-details/